# What do the function cin.clear() in C ++ detailed description?

Tags: c++, stream, cin

Good day, my teacher said that I should learn what makes function cin.clear() in C ++. I was looking for, but a normal explanation was never found. [This resource is cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/) said that this function

> Sets a new value for the stream's internal error state flags. The current value of the flags is overwritten: All bits are replaced by those in state; If state is goodbit (which is zero) all error flags are cleared.

But I do not quite understand what the "state"and from there there are flags and error, which is why, and how well we replace them at 0 value. And what is the "flags" and why they are needed. And as he said that I should know what parameters or data which takes a function cin.clear() and returns, I understand that it does not returns, but it also takes something? Please help. Sorry for bad English, I write through a translator.

Comment: You may want to read documentation from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear instead, most of the time cppreference.com is more trustworthy than cplusplus.com (Neither one is official).

Comment: "I do not quite understand what the "state"" - Did you follow the [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/) from that page to the reference for `iostate`? There's another reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) for those who are ideologically opposed to cplusplus.com.

Comment: `clear()` just removes all flags and sets the flag specified by the parameter. By default, that parameter is `goodbit`, so it just clears all flags by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `std::basic_ios<>::clear()` affects the
`std::ios_base::iostate` bits, which are, for the most part,
error conditions.  The standard defines "four" bits:

`badbit`

Set if the last input failed because of some hardware failure,
e.g. a read error on the disk.  (In practice, I'm not sure that
all implementations check for this; I suspect that some will
just treat this as if there were an end of file.)

`failbit`

Set if the last input failed for some reason other than that
which would of set the `badbit`.  The most common
reasons are a format error (trying to read an `int` when the
next characters in input were `"abc"`) and encountering end of
file _before_ having been able to read sufficient data for the
requested input.

`eofbit`

This is _not_ an error condition; it will be set anytime the
stream sees the end of file.  This may be because it needs yet
another character in order to parse the input, in which case the
`failbit` will also be set; but it may also be
because the input stream saw the end of file on look-ahead.
(For this last case, consider inputting an `int`, where the
remaining characters in the stream are "123", with no trailing
whitespace, not even a new line.  In order to know that it has
processed all of the relevant characters, the stream must try to
read a character after the 3.  In which case, it sets
`eofbit`, to remember that it has seen the end of
file, but it does _not_ set `failbit`, because "123"
is a valid complet input for an `int`.)

`goodbit`

This isn't even a bit pattern, but simply a special value in
which none of the preceding bits are set.

For the most part, `failbit` and `eofbit` are only relevant on
input; you'll get (or should get) `badbit` on output if the disk
is full.